# does spring-data-redis support jedis sharding pool?

Tags: spring, redis, sharding, spring-data-redis

I am using spring-data-redis as the data access layer for Redis, for the data distribution, I tried to use the sharding feature of jedis, but looks spring-data-redis DOES NOT support sharding officially, is there any workaround or 3rd party library can support sharding by spring-data-reids?

thanks,
Emre

Answer (score 0):

I've used [twemproxy](https://github.com/twitter/twemproxy) successfully to shard data across several redis nodes.

I used spring-data-redis as well as others (non java) clients to access it. Since twemproxy *'speaks'* the redis protocol, it is ([almost](https://github.com/twitter/twemproxy/blob/master/notes/redis.md)) transparent for the clients.

Comment: Thanks for your response. so to avoid the single point failure, you have to setup the redundancy for the node which running twemproxy, right?

Comment: @EmreHe that's correct, you usually have a loadbalancer in front of your proxy to handle failover.